# Call a Powershell Scriptfile that resides on a remote server

Tags: powershell

how do I call  a ps1 file that resides on a target machine? All tutorials mostly say that I run a local ps1 on a remote machine. I tried the following but it just does nothing :/

```
$username = "theusername"  
$password = "thepassword"
$secpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString –String $password –AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object –TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" –ArgumentList $username, $secpassword
$so = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck
$session = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri "https://servername:5986/WSMAN" -SessionOption $so -Credential $credential  

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { "powershell E:\\Tools\Powershells\MyPowershell.ps1" } 

Exit-PSSession
```

Comment: `Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { & "local-path-to-my-script.ps1" }`

Comment: This seems to do the trick - Thank you please add this as answer :)

Comment: Might as well. I expected a duplicate question to exist, but I can't find one after a cursory search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing a script by path (possibly with spaces) is done with

```
& "path with spaces\script.ps1"
```

This works just as well when remoted, so to execute a remote script stored remotely, use

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { & "path with spaces\script.ps1" }
```